# Exchange captions in lyx

Tags: floats, captions, lyx

Consider the following picture

[image]

In standard configurations, lyx provides "Figure 1: DNA double helix...". How can I change for "Figure 1 - DNA double helix...", i.e., I wish lyx provides me "Figure 1 - " instead of "Figure 1:" in the caption.

Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is include this in the LaTeX preamble (menu Documents → Settings.. → LaTeX pramble → type on the right empty window):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1 -- #3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
```

Or simpler, if only  want to change the label separator:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

In case that the separator of your taste is not among the predefined options, said the  emdash (---) instead of the endash (--),  you can also define one new separator options (or just type it as the first approach):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
\captionsetup{labelsep=emdash}
```

Note that in any way these alternatives will change the caption label separator in the editor, only in the PDF. (Remember that LyX just show a document structure in a graphical way, but not really a  final format as the WYSIWYG word processors).